# get json data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hey guys I would like to know how can I get json data with ajax call.

I tried this but seems won't work :P

First I created a JavaScript file to put inside my json data elements :

```
var food = [
             {'name':'bread', 'price':'7,25'},
             {'name':'fish', 'price':'9,00'}
           ];
```

I saved it as food.js.

Then I tried to make an ajax call from an another file, this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type:'GET',
        url:"food.js",
        success: function(data) {

            var result = data.food.name;
            alert(result);

        });

    }});

});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you have a syntax error in your example - there's too many closing braces on the `$.ajax` call, although I guess that's just a typo.

In your JSON, `food` is an array, so you need to use an indexer to get the properties of the objects within it:

```
success: function(data) {
    var result = data.food[0].name; // = "bread"
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type:'GET',
        url:"food.js",
        success: function(data) {
            var result = data.food[0].name;
            alert(result);
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the returned `data` since it's an array:

```
$.each(data,function(i,val) {
    alert(data[i].name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the getJSON function in jquery : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
$.getJSON( "food.json", function( data ) {
    //here your callback
}
```

It will set the datatype to `json` and the method to `GET` by default.

You should also use the `.json` extension and not the js extension for you jsons. And format it like a proper json :

```
{
    "food": [
        {
            "name": "bread",
            "price": 7.25
        },
        {
            "name": "fish",
            "price": 9.00
        }
    ],
}
```

You can use this website to help you format jsons : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

The way you are trying to call your element won't work. The data you obtain is an array. In the callback, you can try this :

```
console.log(data)
console.log(data.food)
console.log(data.food[0])
console.log(data.food[0].name)
console.log(data.food[0].price)
```

Finally, note that you formatted your numbers with a coma, this is not the way you format numbers in javascript. Use a dot, that way you'll be able to manipulate it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

I love how people are completely ignoring the fact that your "food.js" is not a JSON string, it's JavaScript code. This might work on old-school `eval`-based "JSON", but with jQuery AJAX your target file should be plain JSON. Remove the `var food =` from the start, and the `;` from the end.

*Then* you can access `data.food[0].name`;

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are trying to get an another javascript file via ajax. For do this, you can "include" your script ( of food.js ) in your page, using Ajax GetScript ( [see here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) ).

Your code is mucth better when you request directly json files.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo, instead of dataType: 'json' i change it to dataType: 'script' and works perfectly :)