# How to retrieve a single element value from a json response using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is the code I'm using to retrieve a response from a server page using js:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
    <script>
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.certicasolutions.com/items/?x-ic-credential=xyz", true);
    xhttp.send();
    </script>
</body>
```

and following is the json response

```
{
    "completed":true,

    "totalItems":98891,

    "items" : [
    {
        "ia_biserial":"",
        "ia_bloomstaxonomy":"Creating",
        "ia_correctanswer":"",
        "ia_difficulty":"High",
        "ia_dok":"IV",
        "ia_extid":"231617",
        "ia_gradelevel":"GradeK",
        "ia_hasimages":"False",
        "ia_itemid":1,
        "ia_lang":"English",
        "ia_pointvalue":"2",
        "ia_pvalue":"",
        "ia_subject":"Math",
        "ia_teitype":"OR",
        "ia_vendorid":"i-321813",
        "passages":[],
        "standards":[]
    },
    {
        "ia_biserial":"",
        "ia_bloomstaxonomy":"Creating",
        "ia_correctanswer":"",
        "ia_difficulty":"High",
        "ia_dok":"IV",
        "ia_extid":"231616",
        "ia_gradelevel":"GradeK",
        "ia_hasimages":"False",
        "ia_itemid":2,
        "ia_lang":"English",
        "ia_pointvalue":"2",
        "ia_pvalue":"",
        "ia_subject":"Math",
        "ia_teitype":"OR",
        "ia_vendorid":"i-321812",
        "passages":[],
        "standards":[]
    },
```

I want to display only item id's `"ia_itemid"` in a select drop down list using jQuery.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` to turn the response in to an array of objects, then loop through that array and populate the `select` as needed.

Comment: i'm new to jquery can you please give me an example thank you

Comment: *"using jquery"* I'll just note that you're not using jQuery in your code. It'd be a fair bit shorter if you did.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [*get json data with jquery*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565400/get-json-data-with-jquery) (and many, many more of those) and [*From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array). The answers to those questions answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's best to break your problem down into parts and then research each part. In your case, you need to:

- Retrieve data from a server that delivers it as JSON - see [*get json data with jquery*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565400/get-json-data-with-jquery) (and many, many more of those)
- Get just one property from each of the objects in an array - see [*From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) et. al.
- Use that property to add options to a select box - see [*Adding options to a <select> using jQuery/JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript) et. al.

Basically:

```
// Retrieve the data as JSON and parse it (automatically)
$.getJSON("https://api.certicasolutions.com/items/?x-ic-credential=xyz", function(data) {
    // Get the options for your select box
    var options = $("selector-for-your-select-box")[0].options;

    // Clear any old ones
    options.length = 0;

    // Add the new ones
    data.items.forEach(function(item) {
        options.add(new Option(item.ia_itemid));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to display only item id's "ia_itemid" in a select drop down
>   list using jquery

I cannot see the drop down DOM ,instead only ajax & it's response

If you want to get `ia_itemid` you can use `forEach` array method and create an array containing  value of ia_itemid

```
    var a = {
   "completed":true,
   "totalItems":98891,
   "items": [
        {"ia_biserial":"",
    "ia_bloomstaxonomy":"Creating"
    ,"ia_correctanswer":"",
    "ia_difficulty":"High",
    "ia_dok":"IV",
    "ia_extid":"231617",
    "ia_gradelevel":"GradeK",
    "ia_hasimages":"False",
    "ia_itemid":1,
    "ia_lang":"English",
    "ia_pointvalue":"2",
    "ia_pvalue":"",
    "ia_subject":"Math",
    "ia_teitype":"OR","ia_vendorid":"i-321813",
    "passages":[],
    "standards":[]
     },

    {
  "ia_biserial":"",
    "ia_bloomstaxonomy":"Creating",
    "ia_correctanswer":"",
    "ia_difficulty":"High",
    "ia_dok":"IV",
    "ia_extid":"231616",
    "ia_gradelevel":"GradeK",
    "ia_hasimages":"False",
    "ia_itemid":2,
    "ia_lang":"English",
    "ia_pointvalue":"2",
    "ia_pvalue":"",
    "ia_subject":"Math",
    "ia_teitype":"OR",
    "ia_vendorid":"i-321812",
    "passages":[],
    "standards":[]
    },
    ]
}

var _getItem = a.items;
var _filter = []
_getItem.forEach(function(item){
           _filter.push(item.ia_itemid)
})
var _options =""; 
// loop through _filter and create options
_filter.forEach(function(item){
   _options +='<option value="demo_'+item+'">'+item+'</option>'
})
$("#demoApp").append(_options); //Append with select element
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/z0j7yu7m/1/)